# Python 3.3 Write dictionary data into CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, export-to-csv

Using Python 3.3.5 on windows 7 32 bit, I have created a dictionary with 14 key: value pairs, sample is as below -

{'Name': 'ABC XYZ', 'Mobile': '1234567890', key3: value3 and so on}

I am trying to write this data into CSV in the following format -
all keys in one row and below that, all values -

Name , Mobile , key3

ABC XYZ, 1234567890, value3 so on for 14 key:value pairs

The code that I am using -

```
with open("Parsed_CSV.csv", "w") as f:  
            w = csv.write(f)
            w.writerow(my_dictionary.keys())
            w.writerow(my_dictionary.values())
```

I am getting error -

```
  w = csv.write(f)
TypeError: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

I also tried running below code -

```
with open('Parsed_CSV.csv', 'w') as f:  
            w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dictionary.keys())
            w.writeheader()
            w.writerow(my_dictionary)
```

But it is also giving me error -

```
w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dictionary.keys())
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'DictWriter'
```

How can I use DictWriter? Does it come with 'csv' module?

Can someone please help me understand what's the issue here and how can I write CSV in the desired format?

Thanks,

Sanket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're importing the `csv` module and that you haven't overridden the name. `csv` should be a `'module'` object, but according to your error `csv` appears to be a `'_io.TextIOWrapper'` object. This indicates that you've overridden the name `csv` somewhere else in your code.

The following should work plainly.

```
import csv
my_dict = {'fieldname': 'value', 'another field': 'another value'}
with open('myfile.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=list(my_dict.keys()))
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow(my_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion worked. I was using the same csv somewhere else...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use pandas in python 3.3 to write dictionary data to csv

```
import pandas as pd
sales = {'account': ['Jones LLC', 'Alpha Co', 'Blue Inc'],
         'Jan': [150, 200, 50],
         'Feb': [200, 210, 90],
         'Mar': [140, 215, 95]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sales)
df.to_csv('check.csv')
```

The above is done in python2 but I think it can easily be converted to python3

Comment: Hi, for me there's already a problem in installing pandas module on Python 3.3. Every time I try to install it using "pip install pandas" I get following error - "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sanket~1
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-88pyt9\pandas\"

Comment: try "pip3 install pandas" I think  that should resolve the issue.

Comment: No luck. Again got an error - RuntimeError: Python version 2.7 or >= 3.4 required.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\sanket~1
\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-qtv6sr\pandas\

Comment: Hmm. try this out "python3 -m pip install --user numpy scipy  pandas" I did installation of pandas via "pip3 install pandas" and it worked out for me. Also try upgrading your pip

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
File = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb+')
dictionary = {'Name':'abc', 'Class':'xyz', 'Section':'A'}
File.write(dictionary.keys())
File.write(dictionary.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

if my_dict is your dictionary, then

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict.items(), columns=list(my_dict.keys()))    
df.to_csv('df.csv')
```